# How to fit mutable static array of two different size in lazy static context without any Mutex jujitsu

Tags: rust

I am trying to fill two static const mutable arrays of different size, by passing them as a parameter to a function. I've tried various methods but at most I got stuck at this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `BISHOP_TABLE: BitboardTable` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:18:59
   |
18 |         pub static ref BISHOP_MAGICS: Magic = init_magics(&BISHOP_TABLE);
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BitboardTable` is not implemented for `BISHOP_TABLE`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BitboardTable`:
             Mutex<[Bitboard; 5248]>
             Mutex<[Bitboard; 102400]>
   = note: required for the cast from `&BISHOP_TABLE` to `&dyn BitboardTable`
```

here's the boilerplate:

```
use bitintr::{Pext, Popcnt};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone)]
struct Bitboard(u64);

struct Magic {
    attacks: &'static[Bitboard]
}


lazy_static! {
        pub static ref ROOK_TABLE: Mutex<[Bitboard; 0x19000]> = Mutex::new([Default::default(); 0x19000]);
        pub static ref BISHOP_TABLE: Mutex<[Bitboard; 0x1480]> = Mutex::new([Default::default(); 0x1480]);
   
        pub static ref ROOK_MAGICS: Magic = init_magics(&ROOK_TABLE);
        pub static ref BISHOP_MAGICS: Magic = init_magics(&BISHOP_TABLE);
}


    pub trait BitboardTable {
        fn get_mutex(&self) -> &Mutex<[Bitboard]>;
    }
    
    impl BitboardTable for Mutex<[Bitboard; 0x19000]> {
        fn get_mutex(&self) -> &Mutex<[Bitboard]> {
            self
        }
    }
    
    impl BitboardTable for Mutex<[Bitboard; 0x1480]> {
        fn get_mutex(&self) -> &Mutex<[Bitboard]> {
            self
        }
    }
    


pub fn init_magics(table: &dyn BitboardTable) -> Magic {

    let mut size = 0;
    let mut magic_attacks = 0;

    magic_attacks += size;
    let mut attacks = & mut table.get_mutex().lock().expect("")[magic_attacks..];


    loop {

        attacks[0.pext(0) as usize] = 1;

        size += 1;
 
        if size > 5 { break }
    }

    Magic { attacks };
}
```

Comment: _"I am trying to fill two static const mutable arrays"_ -- if they are `const`, you almost certainly don't want them to be mutable!

Comment: Here is a [smaller reproducer](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27ba18ca9876b9a3b5593a23fd957610)

Comment: I know, I don't care what they are, i just want to pass them around and fill them with a function, i won't mutate them again, that's why i tried using Mutex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `lazy_static` defines a new type for each `static ref` and the compiler can't see that it just has to call that types `Deref` implementation to get a `&Mutex<[Bitboard; _]>` which implements the relevant trait. You can help it along by just derefing yourself with `*`:

```rust
lazy_static! {
        static ref ROOK_TABLE: Mutex<[Bitboard; 1]> = Mutex::new([Default::default(); 1]);
        static ref ROOK_MAGICS: () = init_magics(&*ROOK_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: although this fixes the error, I can't achieve what I want.

Comment: this line:
    let mut attacks = & mut table.get_mutex().lock().expect("")[magic_attacks..];

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can [edit the original table through the mutex](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e221cd820456d5cab75954891d489df9)

Comment: I need static lifetime reference i can put into Magic struct attacks field.

Comment: Oh you can't get a static reference from a `Mutex`

Comment: Do you need access to the `*_TABLE`s after you initialized the `*_MAGICS`'?

Comment: see my follow question here please, thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289820/where-do-i-store-the-underlying-array-for-which-i-have-a-struct-that-holds-slice