# Where do I store the underlying array for which I have a struct that holds slices to it

Tags: rust

I have to make an array of Bitboard's, and hold slices to it in a struct. But I don't know where to store the original array or how to do it?

```
#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Bitboard(u64);

 pub struct RookMagics<'a> {
    table: [Bitboard; 0x19000],
    magics: Magic<'a>
}

pub struct Magic<'a> {
    attacks: &'a[Bitboard]
}


impl<'a> RookMagics<'a> {
  pub fn init_rook_magics() -> Self {
  
      let mut table = [Default::default(); 0x19000];
      let magics = init_magics(& mut table);
  
      RookMagics {
        table,
        magics
      }
  }
}


pub fn init_magics(table: &mut [Bitboard]) -> Magic {

  let attacks = &mut table[0..];

  Magic {
    attacks
  }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `table`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:7
   |
18 |         let magics = init_magics(& mut table);
   |                                  ----------- `table` is borrowed here
19 |     
20 | /       RookMagics {
21 | |         table,
22 | |         magics
23 | |       }
   | |_______^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0503]: cannot use `table` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:21:9
   |
14 |   impl<'a> RookMagics<'a> {
   |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
18 |         let magics = init_magics(& mut table);
   |                                  ----------- `table` is borrowed here
19 |     
20 | /       RookMagics {
21 | |         table,
   | |         ^^^^^ use of borrowed `table`
22 | |         magics
23 | |       }
   | |_______- returning this value requires that `table` is borrowed for `'a`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0503, E0515.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0503`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: The first question would be: Why using a `&mut [Bitboard]` in your `init_magics` function, while your `Magic` struct only stores an immutable reference? Passing everything as immutable references would solve the second error.

Comment: The duplicate should answer your question, but I would just store the whole thing in `static`s, since there should be one copy per application anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to create a self-referential struct, which is (to my knowledge) impossible in safe rust. [Explanation by Shepmaster on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/14385360)

There are basically two ways to approach this: either use a [crate](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros) or, if the crate doesn't work for you, it's possible to implement with unsafe code ([I recently tried to to something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76846131/14385360)). Though you should use the crate if possible, of course.

Basically, you have to make sure that

- `magics` is defined before `table`, because `table` is dropped first, which would result in a dangling reference, and
- find a way to prevent `table` from moving which would invalidate `magics`. This can be achieved by allocating to the heap. Merely changing `table`'s type to `Pin<...>` wouldn't work, since it will still be moved with the `RookMagics` struct.